# Как запустить 1 метод при запуске приложения (и больше не запускать)?

Tags: java, spring

Как запустить в приложении на Spring MVC какой-то метод при инициализации приложения и больше его не запускать. Я знаю что можно создать Bean и использовать @PostConctruct, но не будет ли Bean продолжать занимать память просто так? Может есть какой-то более искусный способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует 2 интерфейса для того чтобы запустить какую-то определенную часть кода после того, как приложение стартовало :

1. [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html)

   ```
   @Component
   public class ApplicationStartup implements CommandLineRunner {

   private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationStartup.class);

   @Override
   public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
       logger.info("Application Started " + LocalDateTime.now());
     }
   }
   ```
2. [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html)

   ```
   @Component
   public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationRunner {

   private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationStartup.class);

   @Override
   public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
       logger.info("Application Started" + LocalDateTime.now());
      }
    }
   ```

   Отличие двух интерфейсов в том, что первый использует сырой массив строк (аргументы, которые были переданы в приложение) , а второй использует обертку.